# Efficient way to calculate optimum path by cluster in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance

I have a dataset of coordinates by cluster, and want to be able to calculate the optimum path within each cluster. I do not care about ordering the clusters in any way (so this isn't the same as a travelling salesperson problem with multiple salespeople), I'm only concerned with the path within each cluster being the most efficient path. Here is some dummy data that I am working with:

```
text <- ("block_id   y_cent   x_cent
        1          0 86.32583 21.23006
        2          0 86.34592 21.26965
        3          0 86.32777 21.28417
        4          0 86.35122 21.25605
        5          0 86.32938 21.22385
        6          1 86.20016 21.21201
        7          1 86.20832 21.19509
        8          1 86.30536 21.22023
        9          1 86.28319 21.24836
        10         1 86.27600 21.20099
        11         2 86.30879 21.09177
        12         2 86.26537 21.12278
        13         2 86.27436 21.10759
        14         2 86.29274 21.12408
        15         2 86.28498 21.08070
        16         3 86.20485 21.16394
        17         3 86.24649 21.12542
        18         3 86.20451 21.18954
        19         3 86.24388 21.17954
        20         3 86.28371 21.18983
        21         4 86.26007 21.18481
        22         4 86.26417 21.15848
        23         4 86.24346 21.18187
        24         4 86.23786 21.14750
        25         4 86.24028 21.17758
        26         5 85.83458 21.09636
        27         5 85.88187 21.19782
        28         5 86.25454 21.10205
        29         5 86.21222 21.18343
        30         5 86.22216 21.15054
        31         6 85.65182 21.25936
        32         6 85.59950 21.10918
        33         6 85.32598 21.08253
        34         6 85.82243 21.08069
        35         6 85.55521 21.18281
        36         7 85.78904 21.25499
        37         7 85.74958 21.26402
        38         7 85.91549 21.27784
        39         7 85.87116 21.21600
        40         7 85.81141 21.29736
        41         8 85.69824 21.27207
        42         8 85.79566 21.30878
        43         8 85.82959 21.31363
        44         8 85.77804 21.34154
        45         8 85.76139 21.29419
        46         9 85.67412 21.29211
        47         9 85.78540 21.34394
        48         9 85.72229 21.34350
        49         9 85.75251 21.35174
        50         9 85.72273 21.33228
        51        10 85.69474 21.39794
        52        10 85.63031 21.38825
        53        10 85.59537 21.39553
        54        10 85.65995 21.34239
        55        10 85.68217 21.33520
        56        11 85.38762 21.40342
        57        11 85.36199 21.47532
        58        11 85.37264 21.45773
        59        11 85.41091 21.37915
        60        11 85.44151 21.45487
        61        12 85.48393 21.66811
        62        12 85.58078 21.66112
        63        12 85.54180 21.68870
        64        12 85.62086 21.67811
        65        12 85.59801 21.69405
        66        13 85.62965 21.74519
        67        13 85.59164 21.71804
        68        13 85.59901 21.73280
        69        13 85.60186 21.73106
        70        13 85.58615 21.72894
        71        14 85.42223 21.74209
        72        14 85.43497 21.73899
        73        14 85.40001 21.78543
        74        14 85.49442 21.75747
        75        14 85.56546 21.73744
        76        15 85.38635 21.63870
        77        15 85.43960 21.65576
        78        15 85.35741 21.73981
        79        15 85.31951 21.68389
        80        15 85.31521 21.69784
        81        16 85.49374 21.64992
        82        16 85.65722 21.63587
        83        16 85.72079 21.64818
        84        16 85.63256 21.63490
        85        16 85.65646 21.62013
        86        17 85.50028 21.52405
        87        17 85.41230 21.61336
        88        17 85.66391 21.53833
        89        17 85.44119 21.58837
        90        17 85.57245 21.54461
        91        18 85.40519 21.56703
        92        18 85.42931 21.62131
        93        18 85.32510 21.63665
        94        18 85.36225 21.51129
        95        18 85.37187 21.51874
        96        19 85.75957 21.50509
        97        19 86.01517 21.55289
        98        19 85.86172 21.54278
        99        19 85.80931 21.62484
        100       19 85.72187 21.60939
        101       20 85.72597 21.87745
        102       20 85.61561 21.85956
        103       20 85.63301 21.85524
        104       20 85.57621 21.90503
        105       20 85.59059 21.89072
        106       21 85.77667 21.85104
        107       21 85.76700 21.89142
        108       21 85.69538 21.83426
        109       21 85.72023 21.82641
        110       21 85.63628 21.80932
        111       22 85.68025 21.82371
        112       22 85.65279 21.80758
        113       22 85.68691 21.81113
        114       22 85.62421 21.76988
        115       22 85.63872 21.76241
        116       23 85.60844 21.83434
        117       23 85.59517 21.77207
        118       23 85.55184 21.77496
        119       23 85.56366 21.78844
        120       23 85.59948 21.80092
        121       24 85.56240 21.83107
        122       24 85.56282 21.83471
        123       24 85.39359 21.83519
        124       24 85.55357 21.80139
        125       24 85.51735 21.77419
        126       25 85.58370 21.85120
        127       25 85.61084 21.87096
        128       25 85.52559 21.85486
        129       25 85.53922 21.91427
        130       25 85.45412 21.88206
        131       26 85.67089 21.93965
        132       26 85.70483 21.93289
        133       26 85.57407 21.95770
        134       26 85.68766 21.91724
        135       26 85.61921 21.94312
        136       27 85.66283 21.97410
        137       27 85.63839 21.99442
        138       27 85.71954 21.96943
        139       27 85.68017 21.99348
        140       27 85.63894 21.98225
        141       28 84.97737 21.93042
        142       28 84.63300 21.98902
        143       28 84.88830 21.88623
        144       28 84.92210 21.90147
        145       28 84.92228 21.90512
        146       29 84.99754 21.96503
        147       29 85.10119 21.97525
        148       29 85.01123 22.00321
        149       29 85.06754 22.00531
        150       29 84.97547 21.92426
        151       30 85.18716 21.86380
        152       30 85.17287 21.97213
        153       30 85.25031 21.84228
        154       30 85.17082 21.88729
        155       30 84.95938 21.88108
        156       31 85.16441 21.75878
        157       31 85.04450 21.76113
        158       31 85.05902 21.82381
        159       31 85.01908 21.73900
        160       31 85.00035 21.78922
        161       32 84.97914 21.84518
        162       32 85.02973 21.81753
        163       32 84.90811 21.84523
        164       32 85.06993 21.86186
        165       32 85.00793 21.83738
        166       33 85.31744 22.08676
        167       33 85.36343 22.05680
        168       33 85.38304 22.10104
        169       33 85.38918 22.10781
        170       33 85.36145 22.05842
        171       34 85.65591 22.01718
        172       34 85.59756 22.04280
        173       34 85.59563 21.99338
        174       34 85.61070 22.04790
        175       34 85.59399 22.07905
        176       35 85.55172 22.02003
        177       35 85.52242 22.06459
        178       35 85.37774 22.04271
        179       35 85.47693 22.07631
        180       35 85.54970 21.99843
        181       36 85.58273 21.99266
        182       36 85.56933 21.96981
        183       36 85.54938 21.95204
        184       36 85.54460 21.97576
        185       36 85.50312 21.98531
        186       37 85.42173 21.98364
        187       37 85.36873 21.99288
        188       37 85.43321 21.97371
        189       37 85.42685 21.94900
        190       37 85.40407 22.00062
        191       38 85.31743 21.96311
        192       38 85.42195 21.92883
        193       38 85.30920 21.98116
        194       38 85.23696 21.92306
        195       38 85.26164 21.92340
        196       39 84.79890 22.28108
        197       39 84.73370 22.27024
        198       39 84.65563 22.05850
        199       39 84.66156 22.14506
        200       39 84.70807 22.17602
        201       40 84.84906 22.27504
        202       40 85.17966 22.13878
        203       40 84.84859 22.06098
        204       40 84.79058 22.10862
        205       40 84.90738 22.07956
        206       41 84.68856 22.28907
        207       41 84.82779 22.30070
        208       41 84.78039 22.30228
        209       41 84.71282 22.29906
        210       41 84.76225 22.33086
        211       42 84.55853 22.37071
        212       42 84.51923 22.32529
        213       42 84.62699 22.36851
        214       42 84.66651 22.37086
        215       42 84.49291 22.34431
        216       43 84.68952 22.37099
        217       43 84.72575 22.35902
        218       43 84.70820 22.35887
        219       43 84.64178 22.37120
        220       43 84.67436 22.36713
        221       44 84.69428 22.33692
        222       44 84.73014 22.31905
        223       44 84.67779 22.23046
        224       44 84.60429 22.29762
        225       44 84.65155 22.25575
        226       45 84.40603 22.23597
        227       45 84.49529 22.24281
        228       45 84.58443 22.26809
        229       45 84.59409 22.23394
        230       45 84.59829 22.25254
        231       46 84.39357 22.29561
        232       46 84.44703 22.30280
        233       46 84.46925 22.27578
        234       46 84.41866 22.25660
        235       46 84.52129 22.25205
        236       47 84.30487 22.17233
        237       47 84.45558 22.23191
        238       47 84.37898 22.16621
        239       47 84.43046 22.18487
        240       47 84.45154 22.18526
        241       48 84.51769 22.09600
        242       48 84.55436 22.14137
        243       48 84.57622 22.16390
        244       48 84.51546 22.14937
        245       48 84.63149 22.14019
        246       49 84.45983 22.23095
        247       49 84.62353 22.20400
        248       49 84.56912 22.21290
        249       49 84.54201 22.20328
        250       49 84.54809 22.17835
        251       50 84.00676 21.97773
        252       50 83.66445 21.87512
        253       50 83.84650 21.94241
        254       50 83.80769 21.89265
        255       50 84.15527 22.08124
        256       51 83.70758 21.87988
        257       51 83.74622 21.97113
        258       51 83.74746 21.94747
        259       51 83.63556 21.97660
        260       51 83.79836 21.96437
        261       52 83.74530 22.00021
        262       52 83.79702 22.03037
        263       52 83.68398 22.05825
        264       52 83.82263 22.00627
        265       52 83.71190 22.02140
        266       53 83.62893 22.04063
        267       53 83.62875 22.10658
        268       53 83.64160 21.98653
        269       53 83.71510 22.08841
        270       53 83.63223 22.02763
        271       54 84.46019 21.99294
        272       54 84.37296 21.74227
        273       54 84.51199 22.06852
        274       54 84.58428 22.05692")

df <- read.table(text = text, header = T, fill = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way of solving this issue using the TSP package in R:

Group data by block/cluster variable:

```
df <- dplyr::group_by(df, block_id)
```

Split the dataframe into list based on your block_id

```
df_by_block <- dplyr::group_split(df)
```

Initiate empty list

```
all_block_paths_list <- list()
```

```
for(i in 1:length(df_by_block)){  
  # calculate optimum path
  tsp <- TSP::TSP(dist(df_by_block[[i]][,c("x_cent", "y_cent")]))
  tsp <- TSP::insert_dummy(tsp, label = "cut")
  initial_tour <- TSP::solve_TSP(tsp)
  tour <- TSP::solve_TSP(tsp, model = "two_opt", control = list(tour = initial_tour))
  path.tsp <- unname(TSP::cut_tour(tour, "cut"))
  
  # Save new datasets in list
  all_block_paths_list[[i]] <- df_by_block[[i]][path.tsp,]
}
```

Now bind the list of dataframes into one

```
all_block_paths_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(all_block_paths_list)
```

Visualize:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(all_block_paths_df, mapping = aes(x = x_cent, y = y_cent, color = factor(block_id)), size = 2) +
  geom_path(all_block_paths_df, mapping = aes(x = x_cent, y = y_cent, color = factor(block_id))) +
  labs(title = "Optimum path distance within clusters", 
       x = "", 
       y = "") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]